# Neopixel Python work on boot but unable to restart correctly on Pi Zero

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm dealing with a weird problem. 
I'm using the neopixel python library [rpi_ws281x](https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/tree/master/python) on a Raspberry Pi Zero.
I used to make this thing working but now it's messing up.

I added my python script to the /etc/rc.local in order to start it at boot. It's working very well. However, when I kill python process and try to restart the script with *sudo python main.py*, LEDs lights up weirdly... Like changing color and blinking, some of them are not even lighted up.

I'm wondering if the pkill command does not influence the PWM command. Like concurrent access. Moreover, I tried to remove the boot start and start the script from *sudo python main.py* and it still not working properly ...

Here is the code :

```
import time

from neopixel import *


# LED strip configuration:
LED_COUNT      = 1      # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN        = 18      # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (must support PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ    = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA        = 5       # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 5)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 64     # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest
LED_INVERT     = False   # True to invert the signal (when using NPN transistor level shift)


# Define functions which animate LEDs in various ways.
def colorWipe(strip, color, wait_ms=50):
    """Wipe color across display a pixel at a time."""
    for i in range(strip.numPixels()):
        strip.setPixelColor(i, color)
        strip.show()
        time.sleep(wait_ms/1000.0)

# Main program logic follows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
    strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS)
    # Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
    strip.begin()

    print ('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
    while True:
        # Color wipe animations.
        colorWipe(strip, Color(255, 0, 0))  # Red wipe
        colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 255, 0))  # Blue wipe
        colorWipe(strip, Color(0, 0, 255))  # Green wipe
```

Comment: So you asking how to  reset `SPI` bus ? Check `\dev\` dir for which are locked or busy !

Comment: What should i do from python to unlock SPI bus ? unmount the /dev/spi ? 
And if it's the SPI bus who is locked, why am I unable to run the leds properly from the sudo python command for the first time ?

Comment: hmmm, your spi bus required an minimal setup but your application can't/not provided it.  Need prepare minimal required settings of a bus otherwise can't use it. How to set SPI bus clock, data pattern,DMA settings  for attaching to kernel ?

Comment: Check other distribution (like media player) how attach spi bus to kernel.

Comment: The app does that ! The python script works when used by the rc.local file ! It only does not work when started with the sudo python command. The SPI bus is correctly initialized. I tried the script on another raspberry and it works ...

Comment: `The python script works when used by the rc.local file` meaning when you run python script can't initialize some directory. Need check python script file permission(`sudo chmod a+x app.py`) and path variables. And which python version ? `sudo python app.py` used default system python version. `sudo python2.7 app.py` use Python 2.7.  Your module (neopixel) supported which version of Python. Maybe some hardware driver supported only one version(python). Need grab traceback output on your script. We haven't any information of your OS/Library, so hard declerated any suggestion.

Comment: I added the permission to the main.py. Same thing. I tried with python 3, does not work because of the () on print function. It's weird that same code with same SD card (same OS) on a Pi 2 B+ is working fine...